# Foreign Key issue with Code first from Existing Database

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, ef-code-first

tl;dr Do I need to have a foreign key id field as a property in the related class with EF code-first?

---

Following ScottGu's [advice](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/using-ef-code-first-with-an-existing-database), i have created a model to reflect an existing database.  Two of the tables in the db are: Project and ProjectType with a foreign key relationship. Each Project has a ProjectType.

I have added the necessary virtual fields to the model classes to reflect the relationship:

```
public class Project {
  public int ProjectID { get; set; }
  public string ProjectName { get; set; }
  public DateTime CreationDate { get; set; }
  ...
  public virtual ProjectType ProjectType {get; set; }
  ...
}

public class ProjectType {
  public int ProjectTypeID { get; set; }
  ...
  public virtual ICollection<Project> Projects { get; set;}
  ...
}
```

According to Scott (as shown in the image below), there is no need for the actual (foreign key) ID field to be exposed in the dependent class, ie, I don't need a `public int ProjectTypeID { get; set; }` property in the Project class.

[image: Model definition]

However, when I try a call to retrieve the data, I hit an `EntityCommandExecutionException` with an InnerException of: `Invalid column name 'ProjectType_ProjectTypeID'`

Initial googling suggested adding a [ForeignKey] annotation to the ProjectType property.  I tried both `[ForeignKey("ProjectType")]` and `[ForeignKey("ProjectTypeID")]` but neither worked.

Further googling suggested using FluentAPI with a call to:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Project>().HasRequired<ProjectType>(p => p.ProjectType)
                              .WithMany(pt => pt.Projects)
```

in an `OnModelCreating` method, but this falls over with the same `Invalid column name` error.

So, do I **need** to have the ProjectTypeID field as a property in the Project class?  If not, how do I tell EF to use the ProjectTypeID as the foreign key?

Comment: You don't need to....see Making Do with Absent Foreign Keys http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh708747.aspx

Comment: But it often makes life easier...Why does Entity Framework Reinsert Existing Objects into My Database? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn166926.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is the foreign key column name in the existing database? You don't need to add a foreign key field but you do need to configure your `modelBuilder` so that foreign key names match.

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Project>()
            .HasRequired<ProjectType>(p => p.ProjectType)
            .WithMany(pt => pt.Projects)
            .Map(p => p.MapKey("FK_NAME_IN_EXISTING_DB"));
```

You can also choose the option to have EF generate code first from database.